# PHP class strange behaviour

Tags: php, class, object

I'll like to know if this is a `bug` or `wrong implementation` ..... am try to check if `class_exist`

My Class

```
namespace servers\testing ;

class HelloWord
{
    function hello()
    {
        echo "hello World" ;
    }
}
```

Testing

```
use servers\testing\HelloWord as OkWorld ;

$okWolrd = new OkWorld() ;
$helloWorld  = new \servers\testing\HelloWord() ;

var_dump($okWolrd);  //object(servers\testing\HelloWord)[1]
var_dump(class_exists('servers\testing\HelloWord')); //true 
var_dump(class_exists('OkWorld')); //false


$declearedClasses = get_declared_classes() ;

var_dump(in_array('servers\testing\HelloWord', $declearedClasses)); //true
var_dump(in_array('OkWorld', $declearedClasses)); //false


var_dump($okWolrd instanceof $helloWorld); //true but OkWolrd needed to be initiated before it works
```

Question

Does it mean that `OkWord` is not a valid `PHP` class ?? note that `new OkWorld()` works fine.

How do you verify that `OkWord` exists without deceleration ?

**Edit 1**

I know that `OkWorld` is an `alias` but its a reference to `servers\testing\HelloWord` which is a valid class ...

Thanks

Comment: Please if any one has a negative vote .. a comment for the reason would be appreciate. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's neither a bug nor a wrong implementation.

`OKWorld` is not a class, it's an alias, the interpreter will replace it with `HelloWord` whenever it exists. But the interpreter will not search the strings, so the function `class_exists` will get the string `OKWorld` and search for the corresponding class, which doesn't actually exist! What actually exists is an alias.

Answer (score 2):

Returning false for checking if `OkWorld` is a **class** is valid because `OkWorld` is an alias, not an actual class. You can try using [instanceof](https://www.php.net/instanceof) instead:

```
// Not sure if this works (haven't used namespace aliases yet)
//var_dump('OkWorld' instanceof HelloWorld); // No GOOD - Throws fatal

// This will work
$okWorld = new OkWorld();
var_dump($okWorld instanceof HelloWorld);
```

Comment: I agree is an `alias` but your code is only valid if `OKWord` and be initiated

Comment: @MikePurcell first one throws fatal (instanceof expects instance)

Comment: @Poncha: Makes sense. The alias is basically allowing you to shorthand the classname, but you will still have to instantiate it.

Comment: What would happen during autoloading ??? Doe it mean you would have to instantiate every class just to see if its exist ?? how do you even know the path to the file ???

Comment: Autoloading doesn't have any bearing on the issue you are having, nor does the path to the file. Your autoloader is set to look inside certain directories defined by `include_path`. The autoloader only makes the classes available so they can be accessed without having to make a `require_once` call. If you are going to work with an object, you still have to instantiate it, unless you are working with static properties of said object.

Comment: Did the previous comment make sense?

Answer (score 0):

`OkWorld` is not a class; it's a namespace alias.  The actual class is `HelloWord`.

Comment: I know ... the question is how to you verify if that alias exist ... since its treated as a valid Class

Comment: @Baba:  Why would you want to test if the alias exists?  What are you trying to accomplish?  AFAIK this can only be done using reflection.

Comment: Imaging you have a REST service where users need to point to a class remotely ... instead of having to put the namespace .. its cleaner to use an alias ... ... another Example if if you want to develop and autoloading of classed .. and alias is used instead of the full path .. what happens

Comment: @Baba:  Autoloading does not use aliases.  You can check this yourself by adding `function __autoload($class) { var_dump($class); }` and trying to use an aliased class.  The contents of what gets passed to the autoloader is the original class *not* the alias.

Comment: +1 .... nice one @drrcknlsn .... i noticed that __autoload  is not capturing `alias` at all .. who what it means is that ... you can not `autoload` an alias ... its much worse than i anticipated then  ..